# Persistance of whitespaces after split

Tags: java

Good Evening people,

I recently started working in Java (from Python).The issue occurs when I'm trying to split a string and then test some of its elements.

I checked many other answers to similar questions but nothing solved my issue.

```
String str = "0 0 0 0 0";
String[] splitString = str.split("\\s");
```

The `System.out.println(splitString[0] == "0");` always outputs `false` !

However `System.out.println(splitString[0].contains("0"));` evaluates to true.

I fear that I'm doing something really stupid but I'd like to know if someone could help me here :)

Cheers,

Alex

Comment: You don't want to use `==` to compare Strings, use the method `.equals(...);`. And if you're worried that you might be missing whitespaces, use `"\\s+"` as your regex.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I knew the issue wasn't anything important

Comment: I was looking at the split method all that time while the issue was somewhere else!